# Get Cognos Report Studio Locale variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cognos

I would like to know if there is one way of getting Cognos locale variable in a report studio javascript. I have next code for getting navigator language:

```
Control.prototype.getLang = function(){ 
if (navigator.languages != undefined) 
    return navigator.languages[0].substring(0, 2); 
else 
    return navigator.language.substring(0, 2);
}
```

but I need to get the default language that user select in preferences.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the locale set in the My Preferences for the "Product Language" setting. However, I was unable to find where Cognos stores the "Content Language" setting in JavaScript. Most of the time these will be the same.

Here's a screenshot of the settings page indicating which setting I was able to access.

[image]

If you want to find out the user's Product Language, use this JavaScript:

```
var report = cognos.Report.getReport('_THIS_');
var lang = report._iv.sProductLocale;
```

The content of the lang variable will be the locale (e.g. "en" for English).

Comment: It doesn't work in cognos 11. Browser returns next error: Reference error cognos is not defined.

Comment: I don't know if the _iv.sProductLocale works in Cognos 11, but you should be able to get a reference to the entire report. I confirmed that the method I showed above is still valid in Cognos 11 via the documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/r_prmpt_api_cognos_report.html#cognos.report